# Show PlotLine value on yAxis Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with Highchart's Char Bar, I wonder if theres a way to show the value of an Average Line (Plot Line), show the value in '**yAxis**' or on mouse hover show a dialog with the exact value of the Plot Line.

I already show the average line, but I can't read the **EXACT** value on the graph.

This is the PlotLines from the Highchart

```
plotLines: [{
    color: 'red',
    value: avg, // Insert your average here
    width: '1',
    zIndex: 2 // To not get stuck below the regular plot lines
}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to show a label:

```
plotLines: [{
    color: 'red',
    value: avg, // Insert your average here
    width: '1',
    zIndex: 2, // To not get stuck below the regular plot lines
    label: {
        text: avg,
        textAlign: 'left',
        x: -40
    }
}]
```

[Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.label)

Comment: Yes, that's show me the exact value of avg, but, theres a way to "incrust" it on 'yAxis' ?

Comment: @BennyBuAc you'll have to play around with the label attributes. I've updated my answer to show some samples values

Comment: You can also increase zIndex value to display line above the columns. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/chxsLa9a/.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846502/hide-plot-line-on-drill-down-event-highcharts-js